# How to check if a component attribute is String or Aura.Component type?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So I want my custom aura component to have an attribute that is able to include text or another component. Basically, it should behave similarly to the `footer` attribute on the [`lightning:card`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/specification) base component: when text is provided - text is rendered; when facet is given, `lightning:card` renders the provided component.

This is the draft of my component:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="Object" required="true" />

    {! v.myAttribute }
</aura:component>
```

In general, this gives me what I need. But then I want to wrap contents of `myAttribute` in `<p>` tag if `myAttribute` is String type, and not to wrap it if it's of Aura.Component type. My question is in code below:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="Object" required="true" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{ how to check myAttribute type? }">
        <p>{! v.myAttribute }</p> <!-- String type -->
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            {! v.myAttribute } <!-- Aura.Component type -->
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to check it in the controller:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<aura:attribute name="isString" type="Boolean" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!isString}">
  ...
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    ...
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

---

```
({
  init: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isString", typeof component.get("v.myAttribute") === "string");
  }
})
```